# Error when running PerformanceAnalytics function in R

Tags: r

I am getting a Error in 1:T : argument of length 0 when running the Performance Analytics package in R.  am I missing a package?  Below is my code with error.

```
 #clean z, all features, alpha = .01, run below
 setwd("D:/LocalData/casaler/Documents/R/RESULTS/PLOTS_PCA/CLN_01")
 PGFZ_ALL <- read.csv("D:/LocalData/casaler/Documents/R/PG_DEUX_Z.csv", header=TRUE)
options(max.print = 100000) #Sets ability to view all dealer records

 pgfzc_all <- PGFZ_ALL
 #head(pgfzc_all,10)

 library("PerformanceAnalytics")
 library("RGraphics")
Loading required package: grid

 pgfzc_elev <- pgfzc_all$ELEV
 #head(pgfzc_elev,5)
 #View(pgfzc_elev)
 set.seed(123) #for replication purposes; always use same seed value
 cln_elev <- clean.boudt(pgfzc_elev, alpha = 0.01) #set alpha .001 to give the most extreme outliers
```

> Error in 1:T : argument of length 0

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question without knowing what your data looks like. But I can tell you what throws that error. Looking into the source code of the `clean.boudt` function I find the following cause of your error:

```r
T = dim(R)[1]
...
for (t in c(1:T)) {
    d2t = as.matrix(R[t, ] - mu) %*% invSigma %*% t(as.matrix(R[t, 
      ] - mu))
    vd2t = c(vd2t, d2t)
  }
...
```

The dim(R)[1] extracts the number of rows in the data supplied to the R argument in the function. It appears that your data has no rows, so check the data type of `pgfzc_elev`

The cause of the error is likely from your use of $ to subset `pgfzc_all`.

```r
pgfzc_elev <- pgfzc_all$ELEV
```

I reckon it is of class integer, which is why dim(R)[1] does not work in the function.

Rather subset your object like this:

```r
pgfzc_elev <- pgfzc_all[, ELEV, drop = F]
```

Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation...I'll try your suggestion...all my data but ELEV is normalized, so perhaps that is the issue...

Comment: I can't say for sure unless you provide a sample of your data.

Comment: Is there a way to upload some data? How much would be enough?

Comment: You can print ```str(pgfzc_all)``` to the console, copy the output and paste it in your question, formatted as code.

Comment: I normalized the ELEV field. Below is a data sample.  <br/>

Comment: Edit your question with the sample data, don't put it in a comment. Plus I can't see anything

Comment: '$ELEVnum    0.534 0.324 0.341 0.111 0.315'
'$RVINnum   -0.786 -1.35 -0.383 0.343 -1.214'
'$SMLnum   -0.654 -0.7737 -0.4325 -0.0613 -0.7019'
'$MIDnum -0.7652 -0.9333 -0.5634 -0.0504 -0.9417'
'$XOVnum -0.0496 -1.0473 -0.2286 0.5739 -0.9443'
'$TRKnum -0.7      -0.989     -0.235   -0.09     -0.941'
'$AFGnum -0.633 -0.935 -0.687 -0.193 -1.045'
 '$AFWnum -0.574 -1.062 -0.372 0.107 -1.008'
 '$ASCnum -0.546 -0.623 -0.573 -0.434 -0.63'
 '$Tminnum -1.68 -1.84 -1.68 -1.62 -1.95'
 ' $Tmaxnum -0.8579 -0.3289 -0.8579 0.0679 -0.9901'
' $Tavgnum -1.92 -1.7 -1.54 -1.45 -1.85'

Comment: It works for me with your sample data, even with extracting by ```pgfzc_elev <- pgfzc_all$ELEV ```. Maybe upload your full data on github and paste a link in the comments here so I can try it with your full data.